# How to Overload the Subscript/Subprogram Call Operator in Ada

Tags: operator-overloading, ada

We all know and love `Ada.Containers.Vectors`. Here's an example of its usage:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Example is
   use Ada.Text_IO;

   package Vectors_Integer is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Natural, Integer);
   use Vectors_Integer;

   My_Vec : Vector := 1 & 2 & 3;
begin
   Put_Line (Integer'Image (My_Vec (0)));
end Example;
```

My question is simple: how does `My_Vec (0)` work, and how can I recreate this behavior in a type of my own?

I have been searching the internet for a while but I can't find to seem any explanation for how this expression works. The subscript operator, which uses the same syntax as the function call operator, cannot be overloaded using the normal syntax for operator overloading. I've read the package specification for `Ada.Containers.Vectors`, and there doesn't seem to be any explicit means through which `Vector` overloads this operator. I had guessed that the `Element` function might have something to do with it, but have been unable to use it to define a type of my own that replicates `Vector`'s behavior. I'm at a complete loss on how to overload the subscript operator, even though it is clear that it is possible.

Comment: `Vector` is declared to have the indexing aspects discussed in [4.1.6 User-Defined Indexing](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-1-6.html). Can you elaborate on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: You've been looking for something that doesn't exist, there is no subscript operator... In addition to @trashgod's link, the Rationale also explains [iteration and user-defined indexing](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-3.html)

Comment: Others have answer your question. So, there is nothing else needs to be added. Can you provide a link to Ada.Collections.Vectors package specification? Btw, this package is not part of Ada Predefined Libraries.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `Ada.Containers.Vectors`.

Comment: I did indeed, Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: There is a subscript operator: `container (index[, indices...])`. trashgod's answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help, I'm still learning how to navigate Ada resources - I love the language, but it could use some love on the documentation side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expanding on the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77525126/how-to-overload-the-subscript-subprogram-call-operator-in-ada#comment136673364_77525126):**

As I note, the language defined generic package [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html#p5) declares the private tagged type `Vector` in a way that leverages [*user-defined indexing*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-1-6.html). These [*operational aspects*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-13-1.html) identify the subprograms needed to implement indexing at run-time. The corresponding functions are declared later in the specification. See also these usage [fragments](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-1-6.html#p19) and these related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bada%5D%20type%20with%20Variable_Indexing).

As @egilhh notes, the [*Rationale for Ada 2012*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-3.html) elaborates on this in regard to both user-defined indexing and iteration. Moreover, these *operational aspects* are *not* overloaded operators; for safety, the latter feature is limited to specific [*operators*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/RM-4-5.html).

As @Anh Vo notes, the Ada standard library uses hierarchical naming; using the fully qualified name helps eliminate ambiguity.

**Going forward:**

Ada is a programming language *and* an ISO standard. The [*reference manual*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/22rm/html/rm-toc.html) (RM) is normative and the [ada](/questions/tagged/ada) tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/info) cites the the various rationales that expand on changes to the language as it evolves. When perplexed by new features—which is often—I frequently start with the RM to get the terminology right and then go to the rationale(s), [ada](/questions/tagged/ada), *et al.* to see some examples.